# Android - My Location appears out of street using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I'm developing an app that tracks my location in real time, using FusedLocation API and Google Maps. I use a marker to show my current location.

My problem is that my location is always out of street, following parallel to the street while I move.

It does not seem an inaccuracy of GPS, but a discrepancy between the map and the location.

How can I fix this behavior?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` instead of `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in the Android **manifest** `permissions`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

Well gps data are not precise as they have a margin of error that allows them to be off the road. A solution to that is to snap the collected positions to the roads that are known to the api.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/advanced#processing_long_paths)'s a link to the docs that shows how to do that using the java api.

Note: For additional info, the page also gives an example for raw gps location and snapped locations  superposed in an image right after the example code.